# Multithreading and passing the right instance variable in the threads python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to start multithreading based on the values stored in a list of dictionaries. After starting all sthreads, I have to start bthreads, based on the Backfill value. I need to pass the defined variables in other functions as well.
I am struggling to pass the right instance because of the for loop scope and I would appreciate any advise on how to save the defined variable and be able to call them. Should I create a function with the wrapped around the loop and how to access it after that? Sorry for the newbie questions.

Thank you.

```
vars_array = [{"name":"Jane", "age":5, "city":"Rome", "Backfill":"true"},{"name":"Josh", "age":15, "city":"Venice", "Backfill":"false"}]
for x in vars_array:
        name= x['name']
        age = x['age'],
        city = x['city'],
        Backfill=x['Backfill']

        sThread = threading.Thread(target = sendThread, args = (name, 
        age, city, Backfill))
        sThread.start()
        sthreads.append(sThread)
        for sThread in sthreads:
            sThread.join()    
            if Backfill == "true":
                bthreads=[] 
                bThread= threading.Thread(target=bSendThread, args = (name, 
                age, city, Backfill))
                bThread.start()
                bthreads.append(bThread)  
                for bThread in bthreads:
                    bThread.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Didn't you mean to be using the variables from vars_array?

At the moment you are using the *last* value of `Backfill` from the first array, to decide whether to run any sThreads. And if you *do* run sThreads, you are giving them all the same inputs as you did to the final bThread.

I wonder whether you intended to use the *corresponding* value of `Backfill` for each thread?

```
sthreads=[]
jConfig = load_config()
vars_array = jConfig['vars_array']
for x in vars_array:
        URL= x['URL']
        Host = x['Host'],
        Port = x['Port'],
        BackfillLimit = x['BackfillLimit'],
        Poll= x['Poll'],
        Backfill= x['Backfill'],
        Receiver=x['Receiver'],
        sThread = threading.Thread(target = sendThread, args = (Poll, Backfill, URL, Host, BackfillLimit,Receiver))
        sThread.start()
        sthreads.append(sThread)

for sThread,x in zip(sThreads,vars_array):
        sThread.join()    
        URL= x['URL']
        Host = x['Host'],
        Port = x['Port'],
        BackfillLimit = x['BackfillLimit'],
        Poll= x['Poll'],
        Backfill= x['Backfill'],
        Receiver=x['Receiver'],
        if Backfill == "true":
            bthreads=[] 
            bThread= threading.Thread(target=bSendThread, args = (Poll, Backfill, URL, Host, BackfillLimit, Receiver))
            bThread.start()
            bthreads.append(bThread)  
            for mbThread in bthreads:
                bThread.join()
```

#### Also, why not delay the joining of the bThreads, to optimize performance?

Start all the bThreads first, and then only join them after all are started.

```
sthreads=[]
jConfig = load_config()
vars_array = jConfig['vars_array']
for x in vars_array:
        URL= x['URL']
        Host = x['Host'],
        Port = x['Port'],
        BackfillLimit = x['BackfillLimit'],
        Poll= x['Poll'],
        Backfill= x['Backfill'],
        Receiver=x['Receiver'],
        sThread = threading.Thread(target = sendThread, args = (Poll, Backfill, URL, Host, BackfillLimit,Receiver))
        sThread.start()
        sthreads.append(sThread)

bThreads=[] 
for sThread,x in zip(sThreads,vars_array):
        sThread.join()    
        URL= x['URL']
        Host = x['Host'],
        Port = x['Port'],
        BackfillLimit = x['BackfillLimit'],
        Poll= x['Poll'],
        Backfill= x['Backfill'],
        Receiver=x['Receiver'],
        if Backfill == "true":
            bThread= threading.Thread(target=bSendThread, args = (Poll, Backfill, URL, Host, BackfillLimit, Receiver))
            bThread.start()
            bThreads.append(bThread)  
              

for mbThread in bThreads:
     bThread.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering my questuon. Yes,  for each sthread, I will start the bthread only if its correcponding Backfill value =="true". I wonder, is there a way to save and pass the right instance of receiver to another function as well.

Comment: It is already saved as x['Receiver'], isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. I was just wondering if I could pass it directly as x['Receiver'] or define it again given the different scope like vars_array = jConfig['vars_array']
for x in vars_array:
        Receiver = x['Receiver']

Comment: Unfortunately, The above solution is giving me an error that  the values I am trying to access are a tuple, so I am not actually accessing the instance variable.

Comment: It's really hard to follow, what your program is supposed to do exactly? I mean, at a high level without thinking in terms of threads, what is the goal?

Comment: @Plain Jane  Can you give the exact error message and line? I can't see where I am creating a tuple. Secondly, could you try to create a minimal reproducible example, i.e. cut out everything that is not needed to demonstrate the problem, and replace the call to `load_config` with an explicit constant, which only needs 2 or 3 entries to prove the point, and replace `sendThread` and `bSendThread` with a function short enough to include in your question.